# Windows Service Not Able to Access SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, service

I have create a windows service which access SQL db. The connection string is grabbed from the app.config file .

The Following is the format of the connection string

> connectionString="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;server=xxxxx\SQLEXPRESS;database=Sample;uid=sa;password=xxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False"

The Windows Installer Account Type is LocalSystem.
This service is running of some system successfully, but on some system's its showing login failure for 'SA'.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: By the way, `Integrated Security=SSPI` is asking for a trusted connection using windows authentication. `uid=sa;password=xxxxx;Trusted_connection=false` is asking for an untrusted connection using SQL Server authentication. It seems that, after the conflicting instructions have fought it out, it's going with untrusted/SQL Server auth, but you ought to fix this. Oh, and connecting as `sa` is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite straightforward: `login failure for 'SA'` refers to the fact that the login `sa` exists, but the password is not.  Particularly, `sa` is a system default login that always exists, but you have probably set the password differently on different servers.

Another thing to check is whether or not there are multiple instances on the machine.  It could be \SQLExpress on one, but the default instance on another that you are meant to connect to.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply...solved it..the config file after build was not edited...when changed the connection string in it..it worked